# Is there a clever way to format a json object to be displayed?

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

Lets say I have an array of JSON objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {"id": 1234,
   "organization_id": 12,
   "name": "Susan Taylor",
   "created_at": 2016-07-28T05:29:25 -10:00,
   "role": "Admin"},
  {"id": 1235,
   "organization_id": 12,
   "name": "Jeff Scott",
   "created_at": 2016-07-28T05:29:25 -10:00,
   "role": "Admin"}
]
```

But I only want to show certain fields in a certain order?

```
name: Susan Taylor 
role: Admin 
organization_id: 12

name: Jeff Scott 
role: Admin 
organization_id: 12
```

I can think of some ugly ways to do it, but I was thinking there might be some really cool way I'm unaware of.

Comment: That looks like YAML to me. You can just `select` the keys you want and then dump it to YAML.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
YAML.dump(JSON.load(data))
```

You'll get something 95% similar for almost no cost.